# A problem to calculate antisymmetric relations and the recurring equations

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

[image: click on picture to view]

This problem was asked in an entrance examination.To admit I could not solve it.How do we calculate those antisymmetric relations,can someone help.
And how to proceed about the recurring equation for non crossing relations.
I need some help.

This problem is lying unanswered...could anyone solve it

Any hint or something to move the prove ahead is needed

Has anyone even seen this problem

Comment: This is a nice problem.... Whew did you find it

Comment: Its the CMI problem 2020

Comment: It would be helpful if anyone can share his or her solution. I am also unable to trace out the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (i), each pair $(a,b)\in S\times S$ with $a<b$ gives *three* choices (of including at most one of $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ into $R$). And all these choices are independent. Thus, the number of antisymmetric relations on $S=\{1,\ldots,k\}$ is equal to $3^{k(k-1)/2}$.

As for (ii), let's call a relation *good* if it is "non-crossing" and "without isolated elements". Observe that if $R$ is a good relation from $\{1,\ldots,k\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, then we *must* have $(k,n)\in R$ (indeed, because of the no-isolated-elements requirement, we have $(a,n)\in R$ and $(k,b)\in R$ for some $a$ and $b$; now, if both $a<k$ and $b<n$, the non-crossing requirement is violated). Now, if we remove $(k,n)$ from $R$, either $k$ or $n$ (or both) become isolated (otherwise again a contradiction with non-crossing). This gives a recurrence $$f(k,n)=f(k-1,n)+f(k,n-1)+f(k-1,n-1)$$ for $k,n>1$, with initial conditions $f(k,1)=f(1,n)=f(1,1)=1$.

For (iii), we can do even more, and prove that for $k,n\geqslant0$ $$f(k+1,n+1)=\sum_{j=0}^{\min\{k,n\}}2^j\binom{k}{j}\binom{n}{j}.$$ This can be done just by checking the recurrence and the initial conditions above. For those who don't have this result at hand, a possible approach is to find the generating function $$\sum_{k,n>0}f(k,n)x^k y^n=\frac{xy}{1-x-y-xy}$$ (out of the recurrence and the initial conditions) and expand it back into a double power series (say, w.r.t. $y$ using the geometric series, then w.r.t. $x$ using the "negative binomial" series).

Comment: In the actual answer for part (I) the $2^k$ part is missing

Comment: @Mathslover: Now I see - the original definition implies $(a,a)\notin R$ for each $a\in S$. Fixed.